# limit of a sequence with roots (different index)

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to calculate the next limit:

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2\sqrt[3]{n}-5\sqrt[5]{n^2}}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}(2-\sqrt[5]{n})}$

I've tried multiplying by the conjugate, but this give a more complex limit.

Also I separate the fraction but only "simplify" the first element, the next one 
is also difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way in which you are taught early on for dealing with limits of rational functions still works here, despite the fractional exponents (and is what is behind DonAntonio's argument, which you generally don't get to use on Calculus I exams...).  We will multiply by the largest powers of $x$ appearing in the denominator in *each* factor:

[Unfortunately, this is not one of those limits where using a "conjugate factor" on the denominator and then another one on the numerator will help (and, as you saw, produces an unholy mess).  And l'Hopital's Rule does not make any headway on most rational functions with radicals in them.]

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \frac{2 n^{1/3} \ - \ 5 n^{2/5}}{(n+1)^{1/3} \cdot (2 - n^{1/5})}  \cdot \frac{n^{-1/3} \cdot n^{-1/5}}{n^{-1/3} \cdot n^{-1/5}}  $$

$$= \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \frac{(2 n^{1/3} \ - \ 5 n^{2/5}) \cdot n^{-1/3} \cdot n^{-1/5}}{(n+1)^{1/3} \cdot n^{-1/3} \cdot (2 - n^{1/5})\cdot n^{-1/5}}   $$

$$= \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \frac{\frac{2}{ n^{1/5}} \ - \ 5 n^{(6/15 \ - \ 8/15)}}{(1 \ + \ \frac{1}{n})^{1/3}  \cdot (\frac{2}{n^{1/5}} - 1)}$$

$$ = \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \frac{\frac{2}{ n^{1/5}} \ - \ \frac{5}{ n^{2/15}}}{(1 \ + \ \frac{1}{n})^{1/3}  \cdot (\frac{2}{n^{1/5}} - 1)} \ = \ \frac{ 0 \ - \ 0}{(1 + 0)^{1/3} \cdot (0 - 1 )} \ = \ 0 \ .   $$

Answer (score 0):

Think about the dominant terms (as $n\to\infty$) in both numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2\sqrt[3]{n}-5\sqrt[5]{n^2}}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}(2-\sqrt[5]{n})}\sim \frac{-5n^{2/5}}{-n^{8/15}}=\frac{5}{n^{2/15}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: To use that argument, I need to prove that the sequence is decreasing/increasing?

Comment: No. You only need a simple argument about the predominance of higher powers of $\,n,$ when it becomes larger and larger...

Comment: The sequence may not decrease immediately, but ultimately it is decreasing to zero. PS, that is not to say about the series